# Directory on another machine - Login credentials

Tags: c#, networking, filesystems, directory

My application needs to access files on a remote machine that requires a username and password for accessing it.

I'm trying to find out if a directory exists (using Directory.Exists) to verify I can make the 'connection.

Is there a way to supply the username and password when working with remote directories? Currently Exists returns false.

Cheers,

Comment: full simplified working example here:

http://stackoverflow.com/a/17217167

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately not. You will need to wrap your code using extra code to handle impersonation of a user that does have access.

[This article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/306158) explains how to do it in code further down the page.

Comment: This is now a dead link.

Answer (score 2):

Check out this [thread on MSDN Forums](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/clr/thread/e3db5fe8-e365-46ce-857c-a5b86bc732a0).

It has code sample for using impersonation, and also explains a bit about using NetUseAdd in order to gain access if the machines are on different domains or non domains.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `LogonUser` api to login as a specific user and get a token and then use that token with `WindowsIdentity.Impersonate`.

Link with a [sample.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/shawnfa/how-to-impersonate) (do read the whole post to see it's security problems etc though).